# Python: no fork for posix

Tags: python, cygwin, subprocess

I am running Python on Cygwin while fork is very unstable.
The program always fall on subprocess.py:

```
self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
    args, executable_list,
    close_fds, sorted(fds_to_keep), cwd, env_list,
    p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite,
    errread, errwrite,
    errpipe_read, errpipe_write,
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
    self._child_created = True
```

While because Cygwin is recognized as posix, I am wondering if there is a method of calling subprocess without fork for posix.
Any idea would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide the traceback?

Comment: have you tried `os.spawn*` family?

Comment: Thanks JF, it is something that Cygwin doesn't cope well with. I have posted the solution I had. I would prefer using subprocess instead of os.spawn on Cygwin as subprocess is more powerful and returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved by following Cygwin Doc:

http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures

Comment: Could you enumerate the steps that you took [in addition to providing  the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/137096)?

Comment: Yes,note that you may need to generate a list of dll files that you want to rebase, then send it to rebaseall command using -T parameter. Here are the examples: "find /usr/local/python -name \*.dll > /tmp/file1", "rebaseall -v -T /tmp/file1"